# Add hyperlink text inside localizable.strings file

Tags: swift

Can any one help me to add a hyperlink text inside localizable.strings file in iOS swift.

Comment: Use HTML, Markdown, etc or any custom marker, and parse it into a `NSAttributedString`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add HTML tag to your string like:

"Please click this <a href=\"{your_link}\">Link</a> to proceed"

Then, set this string as `attributedText` property in a `UITextView`.